# Magento Compilation?

Tags: php, magento

I'm running a magento based websites, and the page loading speed is become very slow. I found a suggestion where its saying to enable the Compilation 
Magento admin panel > System > Tools > Compilation

could solve this issue.

I check this option and its disabled at the moment and its saying

Directory "/var/www/thebodyshop.ie/includes" must be writeable; File "/var/www/thebodyshop.ie/includes/config.php" must be writeable.

However I checked the root folder but there is no directory under the `var/`to change the `www/thebodyshop.ie/includes`location. Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder should not be inside the `var/` folder. It should be in the root of your instance.
And it should contain these 2 files.

config.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2008 Irubin Consulting Inc. DBA Varien (http://www.varien.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */


#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

and `.htaccess`

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

Make sure you make the folder writable.

Comment: forget the `var` folder. This has nothing to do with that. Just go to the root of your magento instance. If there is a folder there called `includes` just give write permissions to it (recursively). If it's not, create it and add the files I suggested.

Comment: Just create the files and put the contents I specified. Or get them from a clean magento version.

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions for your includes folder. It must be writable. Every time we run compilation in system->tools->compilation-> run compilation button. It regenerate files and place under includes folder so it must be writable.